# Asynchronous NSOperation Dependencies in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm making a iOS app which uses Firebase, however at a certain point in my app a user uploads a post to the database, this post should contain the Firebase Storage URL for a photo the user uploaded. All these operations are done at once, so I'm getting a nil value for the dictionary value for the URL since the process is async and being done at once, in one function which is called upload. So how do I get the URL value and then post it to the other operation without getting a nil value i.e crash

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()

        let uploadToStorageOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {

            eventImagesRef.putData(self.imageData!, metadata: metadata).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in

            let downloadTxt = snapshot.metadata!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

            self.downloadURL = downloadTxt
            print(self.downloadURL)
            }
    })


        /*uploadToStorageOperation.setCompletionBlock{(
            if downloadURL != nil { queue.addOperation(uploadEventOperation) }
        })*/


        let uploadEventOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {

            let key = self.ref.child("events").childByAutoId().key
            let event: [String: AnyObject] = ["eventID": eventID,
                         "host": host!,
                         "eventDescription": self.eventDescription.text!,
                         "location": [ "latitude": self.latitude, "longitude": self.longitude],
                        "eventPhotoURL": self.downloadURL! //error is here nil value 

            ]
            let childUpdates = ["/events/\(key)": event,
                                "/user-events/\(host!)/\(key)": event]
            self.ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

        })

        uploadEventOperation.addDependency(uploadToStorageOperation)


        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        queue.addOperations([uploadToStorageOperation,uploadEventOperation], waitUntilFinished: false)
```

Comment: Why are you using NSOperationQueue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suspect is happening:

Your first `uploadToStorageOperation` runs a block which itself calls an asynchronous method (`eventImagesRef.putData()`) with a completion block. The `downloadURL` property is set from inside this completion block.

Your second `uploadEventOperation` executes a block that tries to access the `downloadURL` property. You have configured `uploadEventOperation` to run only after `uploadToStorageOperation` completes; however, the `uploadToStorageOperation` completes *before* the asynchronous method it calls inside its own block finishes, and *before* the completion block that sets the `downloadURL` is executed.

In other words, the timeline looks something like this:

- `uploadToStorageOperation` executed
- `eventImagesRef.putData()` is called asynchronously
- `uploadToStorageOperation` returns and is "completed"
- `uploadEventOperation` executed
- `downloadURL` accessed, no value has been set so it is nil
- `eventImagesRef.putData()` asynchronously finishes and calls its
  completion block
- `downloadURL` is set

There are a number of ways to make this work, for example subclassing `NSOperation` for the storage operation and setting it as complete only after the `eventImagesRef.putData()` asynchronous call completes. Or you could use dispatch semaphores inside the `uploadToStorageOperation` block to force that thread to wait for the `eventImagesRef.putData()` method to complete before the block returns.

In any event, the key is realizing that just because an `NSOperation` with a block completes, that doesn't mean that any asynchronous tasks launched from within that block have also completed.

Comment: Thanks, will also try to use promises